# Get path from URI on external sd-card in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, filepath, sd-card

I've just started working with Xamarin and I have limited experience with Android.

I have triggered and Intent with ActionOpenDocumentTree to get a "save path" for files for my app. Typical selector is
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvI53.png)


The Uri received from DocumentTree is formed like this: **content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/12FB-3215%3ATest**

Here is the function I use, it is from Filepicker-code:

```
    public static string GetActualPathFromFile(Context thisContext, Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        bool isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat;

        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.IsDocumentUri(thisContext, uri))
        {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri))
            {
                string docId = DocumentsContract.GetDocumentId(uri);

                char[] chars = { ':' };
                string[] split = docId.Split(chars);
                string type = split[0];

                if ("primary".Equals(type, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/" + split[1];
                }

                //How to handle other than primary?
```

Variable "type" in this case is "12FB-3215" and not "primary", so it does not get handeled.

[When I choose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Co4D6.png) the internal storage I get Uri **content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ATest**
Which then are given a path of /storage/emulated/0/Test since type is set as "primary".

So what is the correct path for the SD-card with ID 12FB-3215?
Is it /storage/12FB-3215/Test or /storage/emulated/12FB-3215/Test ?

Any good tips for an inexperienced Android-coder?

Comment: Why do you need a path vs the uri returned?

Comment: `GetActualPathFromFile()`. Do not try to get a file system path. You can do all with the obtained uri. With that content scheme. You can manage to obtain a file system path for a removable micro SD card but it will serve nothing as then you cannot write on the card. So better act modern and stick to that content scheme.

Comment: The correct path is mostly `/storage/12FB-3215/Test`.

Comment: I have tested the CrossDownloadManager and it requires an actual file-path to work, ref: https://github.com/SimonSimCity/Xamarin-CrossDownloadManager/blob/a126338d839ca11f66d4dff510c33146cb5e087d/DownloadManager/Plugin.DownloadManager.Android/DownloadFileImplementation.cs#L119

Is this a bad implementation? If so, are there other good alternatives for Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin you can use my library to access any storage on android. But works on Android 5+ which support Storage-Access-Frameword (SAF)
https://github.com/madnik7/PortableStorage